# Loop to generate and execute commands doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, code-generation

I have following code for my pyspark script. I am trying to generate a query and run it every time with different values of `i`. The query should select nested JSON elements and calculate the size (i.e. number of occurrences). I am calculating this to help me with unit testing the final table which I am creating separately with "explode" functionality

```
for i in range(1,10) : 
onerowDF = spark.sql("""SELECT items['responses'][i]['id'] as items_response_id, items['responses'][i]['name'] as responses_name FROM responses""")
onerowDf.select(size("items_response_id"), size("responses_name")).show()
```

I am getting error when I run this:

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`i`' given input columns: [hasMore, items, total]; line 1 pos 74;\n'Project [items#1.id AS items_id#149, items#1.responseTime AS items.responseTime#154, items#1.responses['i][id] AS items_response_id#150, items#1.responses['i][name] AS responses_name#151, items#1.responses['i][type] AS responses_type#152, items#1.responses['i][answers] AS responses_answers#153]\n+- SubqueryAlias responses\n   +- Relation[hasMore#0,items#1,total#2L] json\n"
```

I have knowingly removed some elements from the code above to make it simpler which is why the error lists more element than my code here.

So why can't I replace the value of I in each query and run the 2 statements and get results?

Comment: Your example code is not formatted properly. There's a string spanning two lines with an odd number of quotes. The more clearly you can ask your question, the more likely you'll get a good answer.

Comment: I was trying to remove other expressions to make it look little cleaner which is where formatting errors were introduced, I will edit the code to remove the formatting errors.

Comment: It's still not formatted properly. Try running it.

Comment: I made another edit. I added 3 double-quotes around the SELECT query to make sure multiple lines didn't cause EOL errors in console. Now the only error is the "intentional" one that I had encountered first time and which the original question was  about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,10) : 
    onerowDF = spark.sql("SELECT items['responses']["+i+"]['id'] as items_response_id, 
           items['responses']["+i+"]['name'] as responses_name FROM responses")")
    onerowDf.select(size("+items_response_id+"), size("+responses_name+")).show()
```

make sure you concatenate your variables. do not include in the string. instead of having `"...i..."` make sure you do `"..."+i+"...."`.
if u have another i you are using may i am wrong. but also check

```
 "onerowDf.select(size("+items_response_id+"), `size("+responses_name+")).show()"`
```

Answer (score 0):

How is Python to know that `i` in your string refers to your variable rather than a simple letter? Python doesn't have complicated interpolation rules like Bash.

You have to make that explicit. The easiest way is with f-strings.

```
for i in range(1,10) : 
    onerowDF = spark.sql(f"""SELECT items['responses'][{i}]['id'] as items_response_id, 
           items['responses'][{i}]['name'] as responses_name FROM responses""")
    onerowDf.select(size("items_response_id"), size("responses_name")).show()
```